# Why doesn't Tomorrowland share its tech with the regular world?

Tags: tomorrowland

So in Tomorrowland many of the world's dreamers and geniuses get sequestered away in a utopia where they work together to create some amazing stuff, such as

> anti-aging drink, great AI and robots indistinguishable from humans (even in the 1960s!), control of gravity, casual interstellar travel, tachyon-based engineering, portal technology, etc.

So my question is:

> We could use all that stuff in the regular world.  Why the hell aren't they piping these discoveries back to us?  How is it good to rob the world of its geniuses and not give back their discoveries?

Comment: I think I just realized Tomorrowland is a metaphor for the USA.

Comment: Not sure the first part is a spoiler.  Pretty sure that is also the premise of the Disney World attraction of the same name.  We also get the idea that it's a very futuristic place in another dimension from the previews.  The second part is probably a spoiler, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During the movie, you hear Walker say that they were planning on going public. But something happened that kept it from going forward. That thing that happened was the item that Walker created.

> Why share your technology with a society that is doomed?